# How can I add a Popup to the root ApplicationWindow inside a nested Item?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a [`Popup` modal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) that covers the entire root [`ApplicationWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html), but I would like to instantiate this `Popup` within the widget container I'm building which will be deeply nested withing the QML hierarchy.  Unfortunately, instantiating a `Popup` that is not a direct child of the `ApplicationWindow` and is scrolled out of view does not center and cover the `ApplicationWindow`.

In the below code, I've instantiated a `Popup` in a child `Item`, but I can't figure out how to make it center on the viewport:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
  id: root;
  visible: true
  width: 100
  height: 150

  Flickable {
    id: flickable;
    contentHeight: col_layout.height;
    anchors.fill: parent;
    ColumnLayout {
      id: col_layout;
      Rectangle {color:'green'; width:100; height: 100}
      Rectangle {color:'red';   width:100; height: 100;
        Popup{
          id: popup;
          modal: true;
          visible: true;
          Rectangle{ color:'blue'; width:200; height: 200; }
        }
      }
    }
    MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent;
      onClicked: {
        popup.open();
        popup.visible = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This yields ( the blue `Rectangle` is the modal content):

[image]

Do I have to put a `Popup` in the global scope of the `ApplicationWindow` or is there some way to instantiate and control the `Popup` in some child `Item` or module?

I've tried setting the `parent` attribute of the `Popup` to `root` to no avail.  I'd really like to avoid jamming every conceivable popup into the root `ApplicationWindow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set the parent of the `Popup` to `root`, as `root` is not an `Item`-type. Therefore it can't be `parent`.

You could however parent it to `root.contentItem`.

As you might declare the `Popup` in some other file, and therefore might shadow the `id: root`, I'd vote for the usage of the attached property `ApplicationWindow` instead, which is available, if you use it.

```
Popup {
    id: popup;
    modal: true;
    visible: true;
    parent: ApplicationWindow.contentItem // This will do the trick
    Rectangle{ color:'blue'; width:200; height: 200; }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between that and `ApplicationWindow.overlay`?

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#attached-applicationwindow-properties)  shows parenting the `Popup` to `ApplicationWindow.overlay`